# MongoConnectionException- Found unknown connection string option 'database' with value 'db_name'

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I was trying to install a library for running ftp functions in Laravel 5.4, by making some changes in the composer.json file, which ended giving me the following error:

**Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found** .

So I then reverted the changes made in composer.json and ran 'composer update ' command, and now for some of the pages of my application, the following error gets displayed: **MongoConnectionException- Found unknown connection string option 'database' with value 'db_name'**

What could possibly be the reason here, as some of the tabs work fine, while some display the above message.

Comment: Do I need to make any modifications in any of the files, as I am clearly unaware what needs to be done here, none of the files excluding composer.json were modified here.